# What is the equivalent of Oracle's LAST_DAY() function in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have used the [LAST_DAY() function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm) in Oracle like this:

`Last_Day( to_date( '$pay_first_day' , 'YYYY-mm-dd') )`

What do i have to do in SQL server 2008 R2 database to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Date) + 1, 0) - 1
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2012 introduces a new date function called EOMONTH which returns the last day of the month that contains the specified date, with an optional offset.

```
EOMONTH ( <start_date> [, <month_to_add> ] )
```

> For instance
>
> ```
> select EOMONTH('01/07/2018')
> ```
>
> Would return
>
> ```
> 2018-01-31
> ```

Answer (score 1):

-- Wrapping the answer in a function for seamless transition.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LAST_DAY]
(
    @inDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @inDate) + 1, 0) - 1
END
-- TO TEST:  SELECT dbo.LAST_DAY(getDate()) as LastDayOfThisMonth
```

-- note: Please mark as answer if this helps you better then the one before.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this, it should work as expected :

```
SELECT DATEADD (DAY, -1, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, '$pay_first_day') + 1, 0))
```

It would return the last day equivalent of the given date in this format : `'2013-02-28 00:00:00.000'` if your `$pay_first_day` is in February, and it would return `'2013-04-30 00:00:00.000'` if your `$pay_first_day` is in April.

Comment: quite helpful for me, Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score -1):

Here are two UDF for begin and end of month.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.End_of_month (@Date datetime)  
RETURNS datetime AS  
BEGIN 
     DECLARE @ret datetime
     SET @Ret=DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(@Date)+1,@Date);
     SET @Ret=DATEADD(Month,1,@Ret);
     SET @Ret=DATEADD(Day,-1,@Ret);
     RETURN(@Ret)
END

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Begin_of_month (@Date datetime)  
RETURNS datetime AS  
BEGIN 
     DECLARE @ret datetime
     SET @Ret=DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(@Date)+1,@Date);
     RETURN(@Ret)
END
```