# SQL Server finding end date of the month - month range

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my SQL Server procedure, I have one input parameter like `created_date`.

Based on that created date I have to find out first and last date of the month.

```
For example,
```

If created_date is `12-08-2016`,

```
start_date should be '01-08-2016'
end_date should be '31-08-2016'
```

If Created_date is 15-06-2016

```
start_date should be '01-06-2016 00:00:00'
end_date should be '30-06-2016 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Use google: https://sqlandme.com/2011/05/16/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-a-month-tsql/

Comment: got answer by below URL, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277504/what-is-the-equivalent-of-oracles-last-day-function-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is in `DD-MM-YYYY` format, so it is need to covert first as `MM-DD-YYYY` then only it is easy to find the first and last day of the month.

The below query will accept the input and return the result in your expected format:

```
DECLARE @datevalue AS VARCHAR(20) = '15-06-2016'; --12-08-2016';
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, @datevalue, 105)), 0), 105) [start_date],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CONVERT(DATETIME, @datevalue, 105)) + 1, 0)), 105) [end_date]
```

Output:

```
start_date  end_date
----------------------
01-06-2016  30-06-2016
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as monthfirstdate,
CAST(EOMONTH(GETDATE()) as DATETIME) as monthlastdate
```

EOMONTH works from SQL server 2012